# Protect sidekiq admin with devise (documented way not working)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, sidekiq

I have an app that uses devise/omniauth for authentication, and runs a bunch of sidekiq workers.

I would like to protect /sidekiq and /sidekiq_monitor routes with devise as well, but so far I am running into a lot of trouble doing that.

The documented solution is to do this in routes.rb:

```
authenticate :user do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

But that isn't working for me - what happens when I add that is that if a user goes to /sidekiq they are prompted to login regardless of their auth status, and if they login and go back to /sidekiq they are once again prompted to login.

Possible wrinkles - I am logging in via omniauth-saml, which means some redirects are happening in the mix here - but that's working fine with all other auth on my site. I am also only using a very minimal bit of devise, just:

```
devise :rememberable, :trackable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:saml]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing in your routes.rb file to this:

```
authenticate :user do
  mount Sidekiq::Web, at: "/sidekiq"
end
```

Also notice that :user refers to your app user model. If your user model has another name, let's say :admin, you should replace :user to :admin in the snipped code above.

Comment: Had to take the answer away - it looked like it worked at first, but upon reloading a few times the problem came back.

Comment: I think this worked. Something wonky was going on with my browser cache that made it hard to tell.

Answer (score -2):

try this inside of your routes:

```
Sidekiq::Web.use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
   username == USERNAME && password == PASSWORD
end if Rails.env.production?

mount Sidekiq::Web, at: "/sidekiq"
```

Comment: This wouldn't add devise auth to the page, it would add a completely unrelated basic auth to it. Would probably work, but isn't the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: yeah--it doesn't add devise auth. This is lightweight, it works, and you aren't relying on trying to tap into the black box that is devise.